# Show total up and down votes

Tags: support

The faq claims that at 750 rep, one can see the total up and down votes. I don't see that when I look at questions. Where is this information displayed?

Comment: I hereby submit a `feature-request` for your tag to become required on meta.

Comment: @TH: It would be great if you just use tags to classify the question instead of expressing an opinion.

Comment: I guess it goes to show how little attention I pay to tags that I didn't spot that one!  Whilst I have a little sympathy with the sentiment, I agree with Stefan that this isn't the place so my thanks to Robert for removing it.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to have 750 rep get (some) information on up/down votes. In the case of non-CW questions and answers, just have a look at the reputation statistics on the user page of the person who posted it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to click on the total number of votes, whereupon it magically splits into a green number above a red number.  I'm guessing that the green is good and the red is rubbish (though it might be green for garbage and red for rather spiffing), but this particular question has garnered no votes as yet so I just see two zeros.

Comment: Ah, neat. I see two up votes and one down vote now. Thanks!