# Where are the moderation tools?

Tags: support, moderation

The FAQ states that at 2k rep, one may delete closed questions and access moderation tools. Similar to [this question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/420/show-total-up-and-down-votes), I don't see anything new that would indicate that I have additional access. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the top, there should be a link `tools` left to `parent` and `faq`.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was missing something obvious.